# fetching ID from url to mysql database in prestashop controller

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I have made a controller known as `AdminTimelinePage` where I can add a form and it shows in the helperlist with a button customize.
After clicking **customize** it redirect to fill helperform.
The code also passes its ID in url as `?controller=AdminCustomTimelinePage&id=35`

I am trying to fetch `ID=35` and insert it into the parent ID field

I tried all the methods in controllers but none is working.
This is the class file `CustimeTimeline.php`
`$id_parent_page = $_GET('id');`  method is also not working.
$id_parent_page = (int)Tools::getValue('id'); method too not working

```
public $custom_page_type;
public $id_parent_page;
public $title_custom_page;
public $description_custom_page;
public $timeline_year_custom_page;
public $gallery_type_custom_page;
public $active;

public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'custom_pages',
    'primary' => 'id_custom_pages',
    'fields' => array(
        'id_parent_page' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'required' => false),
        'title_custom_page' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
        'timeline_year_custom_page' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'required' => false),
        'description_custom_page' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 3999999999999),
        // 'type_custom_pages_detail' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => false),
        'active' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Did you also try `$_GET['id']`? Or is it just a typo in your question?

Comment: yes typo, tried it still not working

Comment: You should try rename your `id` variable to something more descriptive, like `id_custom_pages`, because the `id` variable may get stuck somewhere inside the `Dispatcher` class (yay architecture)